# Directive stop working when is nested with another?

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm trying to nested some directives on the examples looks like I got everything I need but not work as I expect, but if I put the nested directive out of the parent directive it is recognized

```
    here is a plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/eZaYTHm274zWx8GPMAS0?p=preview
```

the main purpose of this nested directives is to share the data between controllers and build a set of fields dynamically.

Thanks in advance!

Resource: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: First, post the relevant parts of the code into the question itself. The question should be self-sustaining. Second, you have `restrict: E`, but use a directive as an attribute. Change the restrict to `restrict: EA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems with your code: the restrict property and the transclude/template properties.  See the code excerpt below.

```
return {
    restrict: 'AE', //You need to add "A" if you are using attributes
    transclude: true, // You need to include the ng-transclude directive in your template
    template: '<div> Some Html <div ng-transclude></div></div>',
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Cory and sorry about the restrict I supposed that it was updated(code).

Comment: Oh that makes sense; I often forget to "freeze" with plunker